# What does Canonicalization phase do in Groovy compiler design?

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

while I am reading groovy compile-time meta-programming, I read about different phases of compiler. They have mentioned one line statement as "Canonicalization: Complete building the AST". Can someone please help me to understand Canonicalization phase?

Comment: desing -> did you mean design?

Comment: http://melix.github.io/s2gx-deepdive-groovy-compiler/#/canonicalization

Comment: Thanks tim_yates